# Fragment содержащий recycler view не сохраняет свое состояние

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Здравствуйте!

Возник вопрос, касающийся `recycler view` в `Fragment`. У менять `Activity` с `FrameLayout` в которые я поочередности кидаю свои фрагменты (попутно кладу их в *BackStack*).

Проблема заключается в следующем:

Когда я перехожу в очередной фрагмент, из фрагмента в котором у меня есть `recycler view` и через `Back` выхожу из него, то фрагмент в котором предполагалось содержания `recyclerview` оказывается пустым (ничего не отображается).

Как это исправить?
(Recycler с динамической прогрузкой)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом перехожу в следующий фрагмент и после выхода из него получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю фрагмент в адаптере `Recycler View`:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DescriptionFragment df = new DescriptionFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("description", findDish(offerId, cards));
        df.setArguments(bundle);
        ((Greeting) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.catalog, df)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ну во-первых вы добавляете в back stack null, во-вторых попробуйте инитить recycler в onResume.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean изменял это, но к сожалению все как было так и осталось...

Comment: Наверно при возвращении назад, не устанавливается адаптер для RecyclerView

Comment: @georgehardcore ну меня в приложении есть еще и ListView с кастомизированным адаптером. И там все работает очень даже хорошо. В общем, удалось решить эту проблему путем .add(Fragment)  , скрывая предыдущие. (Вместо .replace(Fragment))